# Objective-C; asin issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import "ViewControllerSettings.h"
#define DEGREES(radians) (radians * 180 / M_PI)

NSLog(@"%f", sinFita);

sinFita = asin(DEGREES(sinFita));

NSLog(@"%f", sinFita);
```

returns

```
2014-04-20 22:10:09.916 ---[8561:60b] 0.239580
2014-04-20 22:10:09.920 ---[8561:60b] nan
```

I require my answer to be in Degreesº, the and `doubles` are used.

The answer should be `13.86º`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asin` argument should be in radians and not degrees and the result returned by `asin` is also in radians so you will need to execute it as follows :

```
sinFita = DEGREES(asin(sinFita)); // Be aware that sinFita will now be in degrees and not in radians once this line is executed
```

Answer (score 1):

Result is correct. Go through you calculation step by step. What do you think asin should return when the argument is greater than 1?